# Am I receiving these errors because my webhook isn't sending any TwiML?

Tags: twilio

I'm writing not because I want a solution to a problem, but rather just for confirmation that I understand the issue.

In Twilio, I have set up some webhooks to handle incoming phone calls and text messages.  I have not set up my webhooks to respond with any TwiML.  I am seeing 12100 and 12200 errors.  This is because my webhooks aren't responding with any TwiML, right?

The background is just that I'm doing some initial prototyping / experimenting for a possible future project.

In my system, the code is auto-generated and hidden.

I expect that if my webhooks did return sensible TwiML data, then these errors would be resolved.

Thanks, 
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

I suspect its this or that your application is returning an unsupported Content-Type header.

If you want to fix the empty response, you can set up your application to return an empty `<Response />` element.  Also check that the response contains an `application/xml` Content-Type header.

Devin